# Two Modernizr tests in modernizr.load()?

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I need to check for support of two items before I load resources using yep/nope / modernizr.load(). How would one go about doing this?

And upon passing of both tests, not one or the other, but both.

One is a custom test that I have already added and the other is an existing test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Modernizr documentation](http://modernizr.com/docs/) has the answer for you:

Taken from the docs...

> Modernizr.load is small and simple, but it can do quite a bit of heavy-lifting for you. Here is a slightly more complicated example of using Modernizr.load when your scripts rely on more than one Modernizr feature-test. A good technique is to wrap up multiple polyfill scripts into a single 'oldbrowser' type script, that way you don’t end up loading too many scripts at once. Here's how that might work:

```
Modernizr.load([
  {
    test : Modernizr.fontface && Modernizr.canvas && Modernizr.cssgradients,
    nope : ['presentational-polyfill.js', 'presentational.css']
  }
]);
```

So as you see, the answer is simply to put all the tests you need together into a boolean expression.

I've simplified the example from the docs, and in fact the examples given in the docs go into even more detail, so do go and read them as well as it might give you an even better way of doing what you're after.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I should have read the docs more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

@Spudley answer is great but maybe its more helpful some of case

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
      test:  Modernizr.input.autofocus || Modernizr.cssanimations,
    nope: 'jquery.js'
   },
   {
    test: Modernizr.input.autofocus,
    nope: 'autofocus.js'
   },
   {
     test: Modernizr.cssanimations,
     nope: 'animations.js'
   }
   ]);
```